# Tool for DB2 like sqldeveloper

Tags: db2, db2-connect

Is there any tool similar to Oracle SQL Developer for DB2?

I found tool called DB2 Connect but there is no free edition for personal use.

I need to use it for DB2 Express edition for Linux and Windows.

Comment: SQL Squirrel will work with any relational database that has a JDBC driver.

Comment: [IBM Data Studio](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/data-studio)

Comment: @mustaccio is this software free?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Data Studio is free to download, if you have a (free) IBM account.